# Failed to setup https connection of HLS streaming by android app

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, http-live-streaming

I want to develop an android app to do video streaming from an nginx server by https connection, but I was not successful.  When I am back to use http connections or by disable server certificate checking, the video streaming is back.

I based on the codes provided by stackoverflow.  Can anyone review my code and fix my issue?

Below is the codes used :

```
        ByteArrayInputStream derInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateString.getBytes());
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(derInputStream);
        String alias = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null);
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(trustStore, null);
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        String url = "https://222.167.1.207:8443/live/WOW/master.m3u8";

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);
        URL httpsUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) httpsUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```